# Cannot compile C code on Mac

Tags: c, macos, compilation

I downloaded GlimmerHMM from ftp://ftp.cbcb.umd.edu/pub/software/glimmerhmm 
However, I'd like to run it on Mac OSX, so in /sources folder in terminal I ran

```
gcc -o glimmerhmm glimmerhmm.c
```

Could anybody please give me a hand how to make it work? Thanks in advance!

**All it does right now is generate lots of errors:**

```
In file included from glimmerhmm.c:1:
./delcher.h:41:1: error: unknown type name 'template'
template <class DT>

^
./delcher.h:41:10: error: expected identifier or '('
template <class DT>
         ^

./delcher.h:43:1: error: unknown type name 'template'
template <class DT>

^
./delcher.h:43:10: error: expected identifier or '('
template <class DT>
         ^
./delcher.h:48:1: error: unknown type name 'template'
template <class DT>
^
./delcher.h:48:10: error: expected identifier or '('
template <class DT>
         ^
./delcher.h:55:1: error: unknown type name 'template'
template <class DT>
^
./delcher.h:55:10: error: expected identifier or '('
template <class DT>
         ^
./delcher.h:69:1: error: unknown type name 'template'
template <class DT>
^
./delcher.h:69:10: error: expected identifier or '('
template <class DT>
         ^
./delcher.h:82:1: error: unknown type name 'template'
template <class DT>
^
./delcher.h:82:10: error: expected identifier or '('
template <class DT>
         ^
In file included from glimmerhmm.c:2:
./graph.h:37:1: error: must use 'struct' tag to refer to type 'Site'
Site **graph (char *PData,long int PData_Len,char *TRAIN_DIR, long int *splicesiteno, char *ProtDomFi...
^
struct 
In file included from glimmerhmm.c:3:
./gene.h:18:35: error: expected ')'
int  Read_String  (FILE *, char * &, long int &, char [], int);
                                  ^
./gene.h:18:19: note: to match this '('
int  Read_String  (FILE *, char * &, long int &, char [], int);
                  ^
./gene.h:19:41: error: expected ')'
int  Read_Multi_String  (FILE *, char * &, long int &, char [], int,int);
                                        ^
./gene.h:19:25: note: to match this '('
int  Read_Multi_String  (FILE *, char * &, long int &, char [], int,int);
                        ^
glimmerhmm.c:11:3: error: must use 'struct' tag to refer to type 'exon'
  exon *predexon;
  ^
  struct 
glimmerhmm.c:12:3: error: must use 'struct' tag to refer to type 'List'
  List *link;
  ^
  struct 
glimmerhmm.c:16:15: error: must use 'struct' tag to refer to type 'List'
void freeList(List *L);
              ^
              struct 
glimmerhmm.c:18:21: error: must use 'struct' tag to refer to type 'Site'
long int printgenes(Site **Sites, long int ssno,int start, int stop, int ignore,int offset,int *offge...
                    ^
                    struct 
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
20 errors generated.
```

Comment: Are you sure that's a C code?

Comment: It's c++ code, use g++ instead of gcc.

Comment: The application is very poorly written.  It is a mix of C and C++ code, the header files are the main problem.  That is where the C++ code is hidden. AND the header files are declaring instances of data, rather than just data types and the header file wrappers have names like: `__GRAPH_H_INCLUDED` where `__` leading characters are 'reserved' for the environment, so should not be user code And And And...

Comment: Note: the 'tar' file for GlimmerHMM-3.0.2.tar.gz is 44481K bytes Most likely it is many files, not a single file.  Infact, it is a 'tar'  of 14 files, none of which have a proper C++ extension, they use the C header files rather than the C++ header files.  Overall the code seems to be trying to 'enhance' the handling of the HEAP, functions like: `malloc()`, `calloc()`, `realloc()`, `free()` which are all C library functions but is using C++ code and ignoring the C++ functions `new` and `delete`  Are you sure this 'mess' is what you want to be studying?

Comment: The 'tar' file contains a MakeFile that handles the compiling, linking, etc  However, even that is a poor file, as it does not enable any of the g++ warnings (infact, disables all the warnings)  Suggest using some other example for studying.

Comment: I ran the `makefile` under ubuntu linux 16.04.  with out any changes to the code nor any changes to the makefile.   It produced a long long list of errors and warnings, indicating the code is NOT going to compile on a MAC

Comment: Thanks a lot guys! Its just a crap application.

Answer (score 0):

here is the result of running the supplied makefile

```
~/Downloads/Glimmerhmm/GlimmerHMM/sources$ make -f makefile
g++ -g -c glimmerhmm.c
glimmerhmm.c: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
glimmerhmm.c:128:42: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type ‘long int’ [-Wformat=]
     fprintf(stderr,"Done %d bp\n",proclen);
                                          ^
glimmerhmm.c: In function ‘long int printexon(List*, int*, int*, int*, long int, long int, long int, int*, long int, FILE*, char*, int, int*)’:
glimmerhmm.c:645:146: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 7 has type ‘long int’ [-Wformat=]
 nno,curexon->start+offset,curexon->stop+offset,curexon->stop-curexon->start+1);
                                                                              ^
glimmerhmm.c:664:146: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 7 has type ‘long int’ [-Wformat=]
 nno,curexon->start+offset,curexon->stop+offset,curexon->stop-curexon->start+1);
                                                                              ^
glimmerhmm.c:683:148: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 7 has type ‘long int’ [-Wformat=]
 nno,curexon->start+offset,curexon->stop+offset,curexon->stop-curexon->start+1);
                                                                              ^
glimmerhmm.c:703:148: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 7 has type ‘long int’ [-Wformat=]
 nno,curexon->start+offset,curexon->stop+offset,curexon->stop-curexon->start+1);
                                                                              ^
glimmerhmm.c:722:148: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 7 has type ‘long int’ [-Wformat=]
 nno,curexon->start+offset,curexon->stop+offset,curexon->stop-curexon->start+1);
                                                                              ^
glimmerhmm.c:743:146: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 7 has type ‘long int’ [-Wformat=]
 nno,curexon->start+offset,curexon->stop+offset,curexon->stop-curexon->start+1);
                                                                              ^
glimmerhmm.c:763:146: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 7 has type ‘long int’ [-Wformat=]
 nno,curexon->start+offset,curexon->stop+offset,curexon->stop-curexon->start+1);
                                                                              ^
glimmerhmm.c:781:148: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 7 has type ‘long int’ [-Wformat=]
 nno,curexon->start+offset,curexon->stop+offset,curexon->stop-curexon->start+1);
                                                                              ^
g++ -g -c graph.c
graph.c: In function ‘Site** graph(char*, long int, char*, long int*, char*, long int, int, char*, int, int)’:
graph.c:1051:63: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type ‘long int’ [-Wformat=]
  fprintf(stderr,"Memory allocation for coding %d failure.\n",i);
                                                               ^
graph.c:1062:63: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type ‘long int’ [-Wformat=]
  fprintf(stderr,"Memory allocation for coding %d failure.\n",i);
                                                               ^
graph.c:1089:65: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type ‘long int’ [-Wformat=]
    fprintf(stderr,"Memory allocation for coding %d failure.\n",i);
                                                                 ^
graph.c:1233:93: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int*’, but argument 4 has type ‘long int*’ [-Wformat=]
 ne,"%s %d %d %*s %*d %*d %f %e %*s",File_Name,&begdom,&enddom,&bitscore,&eval);
                                                                              ^
graph.c:1233:93: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int*’, but argument 5 has type ‘long int*’ [-Wformat=]
graph.c:1233:93: warning: format ‘%e’ expects argument of type ‘float*’, but argument 7 has type ‘double*’ [-Wformat=]
graph.c:2085:63: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type ‘long int’ [-Wformat=]
  fprintf(stderr,"Memory allocation for coding %d failure.\n",i);
                                                               ^
g++ -g -c sites.c
g++ -g -c tree_util_prob.c
tree_util_prob.c: In function ‘tree_node* read_tree(char*)’:
tree_util_prob.c:64:51: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
     error ("Decision Tree file can not be opened.");
                                                   ^
tree_util_prob.c:67:42: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
     error("Decision tree invalid/absent.");
                                          ^
tree_util_prob.c:70:42: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
     error("Decision tree invalid/absent.");
                                          ^
tree_util_prob.c: In function ‘tree_node* read_hp(FILE*)’:
tree_util_prob.c:192:45: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
  error("Invalid/Absent hyperplane equation.");
                                             ^
tree_util_prob.c:196:51: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
      error("Read-Hp: Invalid hyperplane equation.");
                                                   ^
tree_util_prob.c:198:66: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
      error("Read_Hp: Invalid coefficient index in decision tree.");
                                                                  ^
g++ -g -c util.c
util.c: In function ‘int* ivector(int, int)’:
util.c:84:60: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
   if (v==NULL) error("Ivector : Memory allocation failure.");
                                                            ^
util.c: In function ‘float* vector(int, int)’:
util.c:101:59: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
   if (v==NULL) error("Vector : Memory allocation failure.");
                                                           ^
util.c: In function ‘double* dvector(int, int)’:
util.c:118:60: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
   if (v==NULL) error("Dvector : Memory allocation failure.");
                                                            ^
g++ -g -o glimmerhmm glimmerhmm.o graph.o sites.o tree_util_prob.o util.o  -lm
```

So, even when moved to the MAC, this code will take a lot of modification to obtain a successful compile/link

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am getting it right that there is no my fault in running it incorrectly, rather the code has to be updated by the developer?

Comment: @AntonPuzorjov,  compiling with `gcc` is not correct.  running the `makefile`, which uses `g++` still exposes lots of problems, so, you are right, the code needs to be fixed/updated.  You could do the fixes, but why bother.  Just get an application written for C and study that.